# Prince Rupert's Drops

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

Does anyone remember a short story involving "Prince Rupert's Drops"? Story character finds these beautiful iridescent golden glass-like objects on the beach at one of the Great Lakes, and thinks it's a "Prince Rupert's Drop". I think he finds other like it and carries them home. Suddenly they begin to glow and even burn their way through containers/walls, and seem to be returning to the lake. I cannot remember the title, and I think it was in one of my Dad's old book collections, might have been published as early as the 1930's.

Comment: The only SF or genre reference I know of relating to Price Rupert droplets would be Conjour Wife by Fritz Leiber but its not a good match for what you describe. I actually trained as a glassblower so can ask in my facebook glass page if anyone knows and see if we can get an answer.

Comment: I'm at a loss who could imagine that this is "too broad"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Story From the Seventies: Malign Meteor Hits Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/155956/20774) - "*The scientist visits a friend who works at a glass factory. The friend thinks the stones might be something like a Prince Rupert's drop. While hammering on one of his samples (as one might do with a Prince Rupert's drop), he discovers that the stone can emit great amounts of heat.*"

Comment: It does seem to be a possible match for Dune Roller, have always meant to read that as I loved the Saga of the Exiles and wanted to read more of Julian May's work.

Comment: @Valorum I'd say that sounds like an excellent *answer*...

Comment: @DavidW - Sure, but if OP confirms it, we can close it without having to go to the trouble of writing a worthless dupe answer.

Comment: I believe Dominic may have it in, "Dune Roller". Thank you all!

Comment: This is also vaguely reminiscent of one of the stories in the anthology *The Last Man on Earth* if I recall aright (and bring up as an honorable mention): post-apocalyptic tale of a world war in which heat pellets that were radiated at a constant hot but not-ionizing temperature (something like 80°C) were scattered across the globe.

Comment: Not sure why I seem to be getting credit for this when it was @Valorum who spotted it both as a dupe and the most likely story. Either way glad we got that sorted you!

Comment: Since the previously linked answer was not accepted, I set the dupe to one that was.